# Python Recursive Merge Sort Not Working

Tags: python, list, sorting, recursion, merge

I'm trying to implement a recursive merge sort algorithm with only functions that return nothing but I am having difficulty getting it to work. It seems as though it is breaking down the lists and sorting them correctly but is not carrying over those sorted lists into the next recursive call.

```
def merge(list1, list2):
    result = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    while i < len(list1) and j < len(list2):
        if list1[i] < list2[j]:
            result.append(list1[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            result.append(list2[j])
            j+=1                
        k+=1
    while i < len(list1):
        result.append(list1[i])
        i+=1
        k+=1
    while j < len(list2):
        result.append(list2[j])
        j+=1
        k+=1
    print(result)


def merge_sort(inplist):
    if int(len(inplist)) >1:
        mid = len(inplist)//2
        left = inplist[0:mid]
        right = inplist[mid:]
        merge_sort(left)
        merge_sort(right)
        merge(left,right)


test = [1,4,7,2,6,9,8,5,3,0]
merge_sort(test)
print(test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing the lists creates a new list (`left = inplist[0:mid]`). Since you don't seem to be re-assigning those new lists (after merging) to inplist, nothing will happen to `inplist`.

In fact, `merge()` merges the two lists, but then throws away the result: you create `result` inside `merge()`, but you don't do anything with it, so it will be discarded after the function exits.

I guess you need to return `result` from `merge()` and assign it to `inplist`; something like (untested):

```
inplist[:] = merge(left, right)
```

Comment: merge_sort is a recursive function, would that correctly carry over values from 2nd or 3rd level of recursion?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I guess that depend a bit on how you set it up, but I think that should work, yes. Mostly because you assign the final result to the original list again; any intermediate list may be copies or references to (parts of) the original list, but that doesn't matter at that point anymore. Of course, it does matter in the sense of memory usage; in that case you'd always need to pass the complete list, plus the relevant start and end indices (much like one might do in C).